# How is it possible make invisible the custom environment sol?

Tags: macros, environments, exam, questionnaire

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass[addpoints,12pt]{exam}
\usepackage{environ}

\makeatletter
\NewEnviron{sol}{%
    \def\@currentlabel{\BODY}\label{solt:\thequestion}%
    \begin{solution}%
        \BODY
    \end{solution}%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
    \begin{questions}
        \question This is a question
        
        \begin{sol}
            My solution
        \end{sol}
        
        \begin{choices}
            \choice 8
            \choice 1
            \choice 3
            \choice 4
        \end{choices}
        
    \end{questions}
    
    
    The first solution is:\\
    \ref{solt:1}
    
\end{document}
```

How is it possible to make sol invisible and use it just according to auto label?

Comment: Have a look at the comment package

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I'm pretty sure `exam` already provides a way to not show the solutions when printing the exam ;).

Comment: @cfr No doubt, I just don't know it will also work with self baked environments.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I assumed this example was just trying to create the basic setup, but you're doubtless right if the OP wants custom environments.